# Which 3D engine should I use with QT for the best performance

Tags: qt, 3d

I am working with QT development. I am using QT 3D engine to render 3D view from pointer cloud, but it is very slow, bad performance. Can anyone suggest a good one working with QT for high performance? Orge3D or Irrlicht or something else. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't encourage recommendation questions because that's not really a fit for the format.  See [What's on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*  Plus you don't say give any concrete requirements, just "fast" which is like saying "best".  Try looking at existing programs that get the behavior you want on platforms you want and find out what they're written with.

Comment: Qt is C++. Use any C++ engine. Irrlicht / unreal / CryEngine etc. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that integration of 3rd party 3D engine would be easier for you than fixing the code you already have. If all you need is drawing those point clouds then think about your code from the GPU standpoint - do you upload all your points to the GPU before drawing? Do you draw everything in one batch? Is it animated or static? Can you simplify your shaders and/or blending settings? etc...

If you REALLY need a full blown engine you can go with anything written in C++ as Dmitry said (well, not only in C++ but that's easier). But bear in mind that you'll need to learn engine-specific API and you'll need to do many things in some specific way. You may also encounter bugs in your chosen engine, that you'll need to fix or work around. Besides all of this you'll add few MB or more of additional dll's, which make your project bigger and slower to load.

If you still want to have 3rd party engine integrated here are few links you could start from. Few for Ogre:

[http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Integrating+Ogre+into+QT5](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Integrating%20Ogre%20into%20QT5)

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/QtOgre

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=515314

I've used QtOgre once but it was few years ago, with 4.x Qt, I'm not sure how does it work with Qt5.

If you need a broader view here's a Qt page about possible integrations:
https://wiki.qt.io/Using_3D_engines_with_Qt